# Is there a way in C# to initialize jagged arrays similarly as in Java

Tags: java, c#, syntax

In Java, I can do the following:

```
String[][] map = {
        {"1.0, ", "1.1, ", "1.2, ", "1.3, ", "1.0, "},
        {"A, ", "B, ", "C, ", "D, ", "E, "},
        {"X, ", "XX, ", "XXX, ", "XXXX, ", "XXXX, "},
                     };
```

but the same code does not compile in C#. I could do it in a tedious way by initializing the sub-fields one by one but I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing you can do in `C#` is to add `new []` before each array initializer:

```
String[][] map = {
                    new [] {"1.0, ", "1.1, ", "1.2, ", "1.3, ", "1.0, "},
                    new [] {"A, ", "B, ", "C, ", "D, ", "E, "},
                    new [] {"X, ", "XX, ", "XXX, ", "XXXX, ", "XXXX, "},
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];

jaggedArray[0] = new int[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new int[4];
jaggedArray[2] = new int[2];
```

Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396